# How to prevent systemd from starting services that have RequriedBy on a particular service and/or target

Tags: systemd, services, runlevel

I am trying to write a simple service that just checks if a USB device is connected. Below,is the unit file's content for the service:

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/check-usb.service 
[Unit]
Description=Check USB storage

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | grep -o "ProdID=5567"'
Before=multi-user.target

[Install]
RequiredBy=multi-user.target, graphical.target
```

I am aware that there might be better ways to check this but it's the first solution that popped in my head.
My target behavior would be:
1. USB with that id is connected, boot normally
2. USB with that id is not found, service will be in status failed and I don't want any services being loaded up above the emergency.target (i want it to start in single user mode)

My confusion starts with the fact that, even if this service runs or not, the system will always load all the necessary services and boot into graphical mode.
If i check the status, as below, i see that the graphical.target appears inactive:

```
systemctl list-units --type=target --state=inactive
  UNIT               LOAD      ACTIVE   SUB  DESCRIPTION                                                                      
● all.target         not-found inactive dead all.target                                                                       
  emergency.target   loaded    inactive dead Emergency Mode                                                                   
  getty-pre.target   loaded    inactive dead Login Prompts (Pre)                                                              
  graphical.target   loaded    inactive dead Graphical Interface                                                              
  multi-user.target  loaded    inactive dead Multi-User System                                                                
  network-pre.target loaded    inactive dead Network (Pre)                                                                    
  rescue.target      loaded    inactive dead Rescue Mode                                                                      
  shutdown.target    loaded    inactive dead Shutdown                                                                         
  umount.target      loaded    inactive dead Unmount All Filesystems
```

If I list the dependencies of graphical.target, i can see that my custom service is in status failed but all other services are up and running.
My question is, isn't the RequiredBy instruction supposed to prevent services from starting if the service that has this dependency doesn't start?
What should I do to accomplish my desired behavior?

I apologise if something is unclear and please let me know if so.
I am using ubuntu 18.04.4 on a virtual machine for testing purposes:

```
cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
```

Thank you, and please let me know if more details are required. I tried searching the systemd documentation and countless forums but I haven't found an answer, thus, I'm posting here.

Thank you in advance,
George

Answer (score 0):

"*[I]sn't the RequiredBy instruction supposed to prevent services from starting if the service that has this dependency doesn't start?*"

No, it's the other way around.

Your service is saying that it is requires those targets to be up and running before this service can run.

It's a list of *dependencies*, not a list of *reverse dependencies*.

- EXAMPLE:

  Service C requires A and B to start before C can run:

  ```
    RequiredBy=A.target,B.target
  ```

  *If A fails, then C won't run*.

Comment: From [RHEL7 SysAdmin guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files) i see the following:
RequiredBy: A list of units that depend on the unit. When this unit is enabled, the units listed in RequiredBy gain a Require dependency on the unit. From the behavior I notice on my machine (the graphical and multi-user targets appearing inactive) i guess that this somehow happens. I don't understand though, why are the services under those targets being started.